# What is the output of %s in a variable of integer type?

Tags: c++

I have this c++ codes.
I take only the part I am concerned about.
What is the reason why %s was used, what information will it display as an output?
I know that %s is for string, which is weird because the data type of val is integer. How this become possible.

```
myClass::myFunc(USHORT & val){
   : (other codes not of importance)
   updateVal(val);
   printf("val = %s", value)
}
```

Note: USHORT is unsigned int
The code is so huge and cannot yet verify the output since I have to compile more than an hour. But I am sure that it has no build error.

Comment: It's a bug => undefined behaviour. (Oops - I take it back - `val` != `value` - we need to see more of the code...)

Comment: The code simply has undefined behaviour. I think there's a general law of human nature that 90% of things are terrible, so if you just look at some random code or read a random book, chances are you'll see something terrible.

Comment: its printing `value`, not `val`, and `value` is not defined here, for all we know it might be a string

Comment: you can always change it to `cout << "val = " << value` and then all your fears go away

Comment: The original code it has %d, but the programmer changes it to %s. I think for debugging purposes. But not sure how it will help. This is an old code, so no build error on this.

Comment: What does the `:` mean in the function definition ? I am familiar with the syntax for the member-initializer-list in a Class ctor but this obviously isn't a ctor ?

Comment: If `value` was a typo, I'm guessing that `:` is probably a typo too or he placed `{` at the wrong place.

Comment: _"I take only the part I am concerned about."_ We would prefer that you take only the part that _we_ are concerned about, i.e. present your [MCVE].

Answer (score 5):

> What is the output of %s in a variable of integer type?

This is what the (C) standard says:

> If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

Since the behaviour is undefined, the output can be anything.

The correct specifiers for unsigned int are `%u`, `%o`, `%x` and `%X` depending on which base you want the ouput (decimal, octal, hexadecimal or upper-case hexadecimal).

> What is the reason why %s was used

Only the author of the program knows, unless they documented it. My guess is that it was a mistake.

---

PS.

> Note: USHORT is unsigned int

Avoid using USHORT as an alias for unsigned int. It's confusing and a reader of the code will expect it to be unsigned short instead.

Comment: @BenjaminT Thanks for the edit. I just blindly copied one specifier and totally forgot about the output base.